# Running total of status between two dates - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have data with three fields. Start date, end date, and status (ongoing or finished).  How do i create a pivot table where i can filter a date and it will output the running total of ongoing status from the first date until the chosen date?

Comment: You have 3 fields, start date end date and status. Which do you want to total?

Comment: The status. I want to be able to have a filter of month, and it will total how many tasks are ongoing until the chose month in the filter.